# Implementation of set with contant search

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, search-tree

I need to store a set of n numbers *from 1 to 10^9*, such that

1. Initialization takes O(n) time - it is *mathematical expectation*
2. Search takes O(1) time - it is *the worst case*
3. Structure takes O(n) memory

Could you help me to understand whether it is possible to implement it and how?

I think one can use hash functions or search trees for it.

Comment: I do not know, but answer should be with 100% probability.

Comment: What's n, the number of elements actually stored or 10^9? For the latter, use an array 10^9 bits = 125 megabytes.

Comment: n is the number of stored elements.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat was actually suggesting a solution: a perfect hash function is a particular kind of hash function that has the property of not producing any collisions (thereby guaranteeing O(1) lookups). In this case specifically, dynamic perfect hashing sounds like it would give you the O(N) initialization you want.

Comment: Also investigate [Cuckoo hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing).

Comment: @David Eisenstat, does it takes a linear memory in the worst case?

Comment: Almost any datastructure satisfies the conditions of the question, since the maximum size of the set is bounded (10^9).

Comment: Perfect hashing maps n entries to n keys, so it would always be O(n) space.